# How to make one Model for similar tables?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have several similar tables in DB. 
Now I use for each table own Model and Repository
But I think, this is not right decision.
Can I make a one Model and Repository for all similar tables?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BEDROOM", schema = "public")
public class BedroomModel extends AllFinishProductModel{

    @Column(name = "PHOTO")
    private String photo;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "STRUCTURE") //organza, curtain ....
    private String structure;
    @Column(name = "PAINT") //abstraction, geometric  ....
    private String paint;
    @Column(name = "HEIGHT")
    private String height;
    @Column(name = "COLOR")
    private String color;
    @Column(name = "QUANTITY")
    private Double quantity;
    @Column(name = "PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(name = "SEWED")
    private String itIsSewed;
    ... getters and setters
}
```

I have a similar tables: CABINET, GUESTROOM, CHILDREN_ROOM, KITCHEN, CURTAIN and TULLE. 
Which code should be used for repository? 

 I tried to find answers to the questions inhttps://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

 But I don't find answers here.

Can you give advice, how to make it or link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use entity inheritance with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation on parent class to get common properties in child classes/tables.

So, for example you have a parent `Room` entity with common properties, which you annotate with `@MappedSuperclass`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Room {
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    // some more common properties
}
```

And concrete rooms, e.g.:

```
@Entity
public class Bedroom extends Room
{
    // common properties will be inherited
    private Bed bed;
    private NightLamp nightLamp;
}
```

Now, the important part is that `Room` is not mapped as any table. The room is a "virtual" table, which doesn't exist in the db. Only concrete entities exist as tables, like `Bedroom`.

Here you have the link to the official javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: Can you give me link which explain how to do it?

Comment: something I understood, but what will be with Repositories? How I can send request to table in DB, which I need?

Comment: Well, simply create repository for each concrete entity (`BedroomRepository` etc.). It's extremely simple in Spring - all you need to do is to extend `JpaRepository` interface and Spring will create and inject an instance for you.